# How do I use a global session element in html script?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the script to read the global element, detect if its value equals 1 and if so, display a load of text but for some reason it doesn't seem to work.

```js
var z = sessionStorage["system"]
if (z == 1) {
  document.getElementById("titlesystem").innerHTML = "Your System";
  document.getElementById("bodysystem").innerHTML = "Amazing!
}
```

```html
<h2 id="titlesystem"></h2>
<p id="bodysystem"></p>
```

Comment: There's no PHP in your code, why did you use that tag?

Comment: You do not need the wrapping `{}` and your image is the same as the code

Comment: Do you mean `sessionStorage.getItem("system")`

Comment: `innerHTML = "Amazing!` - You never close the string (missing `"` in the end). Copy/paste typo?

Comment: You should also include what debugging you've done. Do you have any errors in the console? Have you checked that `sessionStorage["system"]` contains what you think? How, where and when are you storing the value? Please give us more info.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, you want to read some value stored in session (in php stored in `$_SESSION`) as a client from javascript.

First: session is server-side thing, clients don't know that they are in session.

But there is a way, how to send value.
This is what came to my mind:

```
<h2 id="titlesystem"></h2>
<p id="bodysystem"></p>
<input type="hidden" value=<?php echo $_SESSION["value"]?> id="mySessionValue">
<script>
    var sessionValue = document.getElementById("mySessionValue").value;
    if (sessionValue == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("titlesystem").innerHTML = "Your System";
        document.getElementById("bodysystem").innerHTML = "Amazing!"
    }
</script>
```

Comment: JS has [window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) which is more likely what he seeks